# CXF Marshalling error

Tags: cxf

i am getting "Marshalling Error: class tavant.twms.integration.layer.component.hsmComponent.HSMAddressResponse nor any of its super class is known to this context". i have added the annotations as well, but still not resolved. below are my files,

```
cxf-servlet.xml
<bean id="integrationServiceImpl" class="tavant.twms.integration.layer.IntegrationServiceImpl"/>
<jaxws:endpoint id="integrationService" implementor="#integrationServiceImpl" address="/IntegrationService">
        <jaxws:dataBinding>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding"/>
        </jaxws:dataBinding>
    </jaxws:endpoint>

@webmethod
public Object fetchHSMAddressDetails(String addressxml){
        securityHelper.populateIntegrationUser();
        HSMAddressRequestDocumentDTO requestDTO = null;
        HSMAddressRequest request = null;

        try {
            requestDTO = HSMAddressRequestDocumentDTO.Factory.parse((String) addressxml);
        } catch (XmlException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if(requestDTO == null)
            return null;

        request = requestDTO.getHSMAddressRequest();
        return hsmAddressFetch.fetchMelissaData(request);/* return type is HSMAddressResponse*/
    }
```